# swift3 - canOpenURL: failed for URL tel

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to intent a call , this is my code :

```
if let urlMobile = NSURL(string: "tel://076938483"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(urlMobile as URL) {

                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(urlMobile as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                }
                else {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(urlMobile as URL)
                }
            }
```

I'm using swift 3 to do so but I get this error:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "tel://09178883828" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
```

any idea to do so  ?

Comment: Are you testing on the iOS Simulator? It won't be possible there, you have to test on a physical device.

Answer (score 7):

Your code works perfectly fine. Run it on an actual device if your using Simulator. You can't simulate a call on a Mac/MacBook.

Please have a look at [Simulator Hardware Actions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/InteractingwithiOSandwatchOS/InteractingwithiOSandwatchOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH8-SW1) in Apple documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Some LSApplicationQueriesScheme do not work on Simulator. Error Code -10814 is for kLSApplicationNotFoundErr. Simulator can't launch **Dial Pad** for Telephone. So run it on iPhone device.

This worked for me!!!

Code Should be

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "tel://\(yourNumber)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL) {
  UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the url should be:

```
if let urlMobile = NSURL(string: "tel:///076938483"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(urlMobile as URL) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let phonenumber = "076938483"
guard let url = URL(string: "tel://\(phonenumber )") else {
            return
            
        }
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
```

In the else part of the URL generation, print anything, if it is getting printed, you need to check the format of the phone number.

Answer (score 0):

@IBAction func Call(_ sender: Any) {

```
    let busPhone = "7355535586"
    if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(busPhone)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
@objc func callBtn() {
       let userPhone = String((phoneNum.filter {!" \n\t\r".contains($0)}))
       if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(phoneNum)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               UIApplication.shared.open(url)
           }
        }
    }
```

**Note**: This code can work when you run with the real device not simulator. And don't forget add LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in your info.plist.